# In search of a $q$-analogue of a Catalan identity

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, q-analogs

Let $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$ be the all-familiar Catalan numbers. Then, the following identity has received enough attention in the literature (for example, [Lagrange Inversion: When and How](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10440-006-9077-7)):
\begin{equation}
\label1
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}C_k=\binom{2n+1}n \qquad \iff \qquad 
\sum_{i+j=n}\binom{2i}iC_j=\binom{2n+1}n. \tag1
\end{equation}

I like to ask

> **QUESTION.** Is there a $q$-analogue of \eqref{1}? Possibly, a combinatorial proof of \eqref{1} would shed some light into this.

Comment: I can only say that substituting $q$-binomial coefficients for binomial coefficients and solving for $C_k$ gives something awful:$$C_0=1$$$$C_1=q^2$$$$C_2=q^6+q^5+q^4-q^2$$$$C_3=q^{12}+q^{11}+2q^{10}+2q^9+3q^8+q^7-q^6-2q^5-2q^4$$$$\cdots$$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: often there are "hidden" powers of $q$ that make these $q$-analogues work.

Comment: @SamHopkins I know (© Zorg :D). I tried $q^{n-k}$ and $q^{\binom k2}$, with no avail. I am now looking into $q^{2n-2k}$ which seems to be interesting...

Comment: Related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393225/is-there-a-q-analogue-to-shapiros-convolution-identity

Comment: This article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316585900895 gives q-analog of Catalan convolution for Carlitz's q-analog of Catalan numbers.

Comment: Also see my answer to OP's another post, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263164/generating-q-catalan-numbers/263184#263184

Comment: Name of @Nemo's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/400793/in-search-of-a-q-analogue#comment1024109_400793):  [Fürlinger and Hofbauer - $q$-Catalan numbers](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(85)90089-5).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This identity is known as Jonah's formula (special case with $n\rightarrow 2n$ and $r\rightarrow n$, see "Catalan Numbers with Applications" by Thomas Koshy, pg. 325-326 for a combinatorial proof)

$$\sum_{k=0}^r\binom{n-2k}{r-k}C_k=\binom{n+1}r$$
and a $q$-analogue was obtained by Andrews in "$q$-Catalan identities" in the book "The legacy of Alladi Ramakrishnan in the Mathematical Sciences". It's Theorem 3, pg. 186.

$$\frac{(1+q^{n-r+1})}{(1+q^{r+1})}\left[ {\begin{array}{c}n+1\\r\end{array} } \right]_{q^2}=-(-q\;;q)_{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^r\left[ {\begin{array}{c}n-2k\\r-k\end{array} } \right]_{q^2}\frac{\textrm{C}_{k+1}(-1;q)}{(-q\;;q)_{n-2k}}q^{-k-1}$$

where $\textrm{C}_n(\lambda,q)$ is a $q$-analogue of the Catalan numbers considered also by Andrews [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316587900331).

$$\textrm{C}_n(\lambda,q)=\frac{q^{2n}(-\lambda/q; q^{2})_{n}}{(q^2;q^2)_{n}}$$

In the paper, he says that the general strategy is to go from a binomial coefficient identity to a generalized hypergeometric identity, and then we can look for a $q$-analogue of the latter. In this case, he used the Pfaff-Saalschütz summation formula and then he searched for a $q$-analogue of this one with the help of Bailey's and Gasper and Rahman's books. I can't help much more, I'm not familiar with these kind of hypergeometric identities.

If $n\rightarrow 2n$ and $r\rightarrow n$, the limit $q\rightarrow 1$ recovers the identity (1).

Answer (score 6):

Decided to make a cw post: it is sort of amusing.

Let $C_n(q)$ be defined by
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}_qC_k(q)q^{2n-2k}=\binom{2n+1}n_q,\qquad n=0,1,2,\dotsc.$$

Then
\begin{multline*}
C_n(q)=1+q+q^2+q^3+2 q^4+3 q^5+3 q^6+3 q^7+4 q^8+6 q^9+\dotsb\\\dotsb-7q^{(n+1)^2-6}-5q^{(n+1)^2-5}-3q^{(n+1)^2-4}-2q^{(n+1)^2-3}-q^{(n+1)^2-2}-q^{(n+1)^2-1}
\end{multline*}
where the “tail” is made from the partition numbers $1,1,2,3,5,7,11,15,22,30,42,\dotsc$ while the “head” satisfies
\begin{multline*}
1+q+q^2+q^3+2 q^4+3 q^5+3 q^6+3 q^7+4 q^8+6 q^9+7 q^{10}+6 q^{11}+6 q^{12}+8 q^{13}+\dotsb\\
=1/(1-q-q^4+q^6+q^{11}-q^{14}-q^{21}+q^{25}+q^{34}-q^{39}-q^{50}+q^{56}+\dotsb).
\end{multline*}
Cf.
\begin{align*}
&\qquad\qquad1+q-q^4-q^6+q^{11}+q^{14}-q^{21}-q^{25}+q^{34}+q^{39}-q^{50}-q^{56}+\dotsb\\
&=q^{-1}(1-\prod_{n\geqslant1}(1-q^n)).
\end{align*}
Have no idea how to prove these, or what happens in between ….

Comment: I'm confused, shouldn't $C_k(q)$ depend on both $n$ and $k$?

Comment: @SamHopkins Why? The "non-$q$" Catalan numbers only depend on one index.

Comment: I see, good point. Then possibly your observations can be proved by taking the limit $n\to\infty$ of the sum, and considering the regimes $q < 1$ and $q > 1$.

Comment: @SamHopkins Interesting idea. But I don't know how to proceed: leaving it as it is, the summands on the left become divisible by higher and higher powers of $q$, because of the $q^{2n-2k}$ term. While if one divides both sides by $q^{2n}$, then the right hand side acquires more and more negative powers of $q$. What is definitely significant is that both ${\binom{2n+1}n}_q$ and ${\binom{2n}n}_q$ tend to the partition generating function $1+q+2q^2+3q^3+5q^4+7q^5+...$